# A white space as a response of an empty php file?

Tags: php, android, http, android-volley

To reproduce the issue, I an create empty PHP file empty.php :

```
<?php?>
```

If I now call this file within my app (using Volley in Android) I receive a String consisting of one space: `response.equals(" ")` returns `true`

It should not be an issue of the HTTP request service I use, since if empty.php is really empty: "" , `response.equals("")` is `true`

Why does this happen?

If I add some `print()` calls in my PHP file, the extra white space is only at the very beginning of the response.

Can extra white spaces appear on other occasions as well?

Of course, I can just remove the very first space, but if I have to assume, that more random white spaces could appear in the response, the processing of it becomes more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, but you might have saved the page as UTF-8 with byte-order mark. If so, open the page into a text editor and save it as "UTF-8 without BOM".
The BOM should appear indeed as a white space...